# Where is my Ubuntu One control panel in Linux Mint 14?

Tags: linux-mint, upgrade

Using Linux Mint 14. Everything was just great since yesterday. Yesterday I have installed some update through Update Manager. I saw there was an update for Ubuntu One. Whatever today after starting my PC, I'm not getting my Ubuntu One panel along with Ubuntu One indicator. They are just gone. I can't even find Ubuntu One in the menu.

I need that panel get back ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem (on Ubuntu 13.04), I had to install the `ubuntuone-control-panel-qt` package manually. Search for it in the Software Centre or run:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntuone-control-panel-qt
```

in a terminal.

Possibly the problem has to do with the transition from the GTK-based control panel to the QT-based (the `ubuntuone-control-panel-gtk` package that existed in previous of Ubuntu/Mint no longer exists).